# Drawing on UIImage that's inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a UIImage displayed inside a UIScrollView so the user can pinch to zoom in and out on the pic, but I want them to be able to draw on the photo with their finger, and then blend the drawing onto the photo and save them. Can anyone point me in the right direction to do this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You need to override UIScrollview/UIView class and override drawRect method..

In drawRect method need to draw image or freehand drawing.

On scrollview bounds changes need to call setNeedDisplay and it will call drawRect method and draw image according your bounds.

Some sample link related to drawing concept in iOS. Hope this help you.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/smooth-freehand-drawing-on-ios--mobile-13164
http://www.raywenderlich.com/32283/core-graphics-tutorial-lines-rectangles-and-gradients
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_Graphics_Tutorial_using_Core_Graphics_and_Core_Image